# 'Too many levels of symbolic links' in /usr/local/bin after performing docker pull

Tags: linux, docker

I've run into a problem that's quite strange. I'm using Oracle Enterprise Linux 6 and I installed docker on it. After installing it, I pulled an image using the docker pull command. Here's what I did:

```
docker pull sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.0
```

The pull succeeded and exited with the message:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.0
```

But right after trying to run any regular linux command results in the error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/sudo: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I tried running the find command under /usr/local/bin with a mindepth of 15 to find out if there are any loops and it gives the same error again

```
find: `/usr/local/bin': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see two similar errors, but I don't know if they apply to your case: https://github.com/docker/docker/search?q=Too+many+levels+of+symbolic+links&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by directories not being automounted when the container is run. I had thought that /usr/groups/thing was the automount point, but evidently the sub-directories are auto-mounted individually. The solution is to make sure each one is mounted before entering the container:

```
$ (cd /usr/groups/thing/foo; cd /usr/groups/thing/bar)
$ docker run -v /usr/groups/thing -ti imagename /bin/bash
# ls /usr/groups/thing/bar
d e f
```

Link to answer from serverfault.com:

https://serverfault.com/questions/640895/why-do-some-host-volumes-in-docker-containers-give-the-error-too-many-levels-of